# How to set text on status bar?

Tags: android

How to set text on status bar (line that placed Battery life, time ..etc) ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a [Status Bar Notification](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html).

```
//Create the Notification
Notification notification = new Notification(
    android.R.drawable.stat_sys_warning,  //Icon to use
    "Hello World!", //Text
    System.currentTimeMillis() //When to display - i.e. now
);

//Create a PendingIntent to do something when the user clicks on the Notification
//Normally this would be something in your own app
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.stackoverflow.com"));
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

//Add the detail to the Notification
notification.setLatestEventInfo(
    getApplicationContext(),
    "Stack Overflow", //Title of detail view
    "This will launch Stack Overflow",  //Text on detail view
    pi
);

//Display the Notification
NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
nm.notify(ID_HELLO_WORLD, notification);  //ID_HELLO_WORLD is a int ID
```