# Displaying text in Android Status Bar

Tags: android

I am trying to display text in the Status Bar of Android Nougat just as time is displayed. I can display icons using `NotificationCompat.Builder` but not text. How to proceed?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, text isn't displayed in the status bar as of Lollipop. This used to be possible with the `setTicker` method.

Comment: Yes. I tried to `setTicker` method but it didn't work. However, there are some apps like Internet Speed Meter Lite that display text in Android N. I wonder how ?

Comment: Did you found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45392031/5272951 ?

Comment: @EJusius I found it and tried to incorporate it. Did not work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840166/how-to-set-text-on-status-bar-notification-in-android?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `NotificationCompat.Builder` you can set text there

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
    new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
    .setContentTitle("My notification")
    .setContentText("Hello World!")
```

You can also address [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076610/how-to-set-text-on-status-bar)

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by converting String to Bitmap. Got the idea from [here](https://github.com/karljamoralin/internet-speed-meter/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/karljamoralin/internetspeedmeter/ISMService.java)